# Docker-Compose Nginx (with static React) and Nginx

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I am currently stuck on making `nginx` proxy to the `node` load balancer. It gives the following error when making a request on `185.146.87.32:5000/`:

`2020/06/01 13:23:09 [warn] 6#6: *1 upstream server temporarily disabled while connecting to upstream, client: 86.125.198.83, server: domain.ro, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://185.146.87.32:5002/", host: "185.146.87.32:5000"`

I managed to make this work on a local system, but now I am trying to make it work on a remote server.
`BACKEND_SERVER_PORT_1=5001`
`BACKEND_SERVER_PORT_2=5002`
`BACKEND_NODE_PORT=5000`
`BACKEND_NGINX_PORT=80`
`CLIENT_SERVER_PORT=3000`
`ADMIN_SERVER_PORT=3006`
`NGINX_SERVER_PORT=80`
`API_HOST="http://domain.ro"`

This is the `docker-compose`:

```
version: '3'
services:

#####################################
#   Setup for NGINX container
#####################################
nginx:
  container_name: domain_back_nginx
  build:
    context: ./nginx
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
  image: domain/domain_back_nginx
  ports:
    - ${BACKEND_NODE_PORT}:${BACKEND_NGINX_PORT}
  volumes:
    - ./:/usr/src/domain
  restart: always
#####################################
#   Setup for backend container
#####################################
backend_1:
  container_name: domain_back_server_1
  build:
    context: ./
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
  image: domain/domain_back_server_1
  ports:
    - ${BACKEND_SERVER_PORT_1}:${BACKEND_NODE_PORT}
  volumes:
    - ./:/usr/src/domain
  restart: always
  command: npm start
#####################################
#   Setup for backend container
#####################################
backend_2:
  container_name: domain_back_server_2
  build:
    context: ./
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
  image: domain/domain_back_server_2
  ports:
    - ${BACKEND_SERVER_PORT_2}:${BACKEND_NODE_PORT}
  volumes:
    - ./:/usr/src/domain
  restart: always
  command: npm start
```

The `Dockerfile` for node is:

```
FROM node:12.17.0-alpine3.9

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/domain

ENV NODE_ENV=production

WORKDIR /usr/src/domain

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install --silent

COPY . .

EXPOSE 5000
```

The config file for nginx is:

```
upstream domain {
  least_conn;
  server backend_1 weight=1;
  server backend_2 weight=1;
}

server {
   listen 80;
   listen [::]:80;

   root /var/www/domain_app;
   server_name domain.ro www.domain.ro;
   location / {
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_pass http://domain;
  }
  error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
  location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
  }
}
```

The `Dockerfile` for nginx is:

```
FROM nginx:1.17-alpine as build

#!/bin/sh

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

COPY default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't expose your backend to world,

create a docker network for your services, then expose nginx, it's the best practice,
but in your case you didnt specify backend ports in nginx.conf

```
upstream domain {
  least_conn;
  server backend_1:5000 weight=1;
  server backend_2:5000 weight=1;
}
```

you should do below:

```
version: '3'
services:

#####################################
#   Setup for NGINX container
#####################################
nginx:
  container_name: domain_back_nginx
  build:
    context: ./nginx
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
  image: domain/domain_back_nginx
  networks:
    - proxy
  ports:
    - 5000:80
  volumes:
    - ./:/usr/src/domain
  restart: always
#####################################
#   Setup for backend container
#####################################
backend_1:
  container_name: domain_back_server_1
  build:
    context: ./
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
  image: domain/domain_back_server_1
  networks:
    - proxy

  ## always expose, just in case you missed it in Dockerfile, this will expose the port(s)
  ## just in defined networks
  expose:
    - 5000
  volumes:
    - ./:/usr/src/domain
  restart: always
  command: npm start
#####################################
#   Setup for backend container
#####################################
backend_2:
  container_name: domain_back_server_2
  build:
    context: ./
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
  image: domain/domain_back_server_2
  networks:
    - proxy

  ## always expose, just in case you missed it in Dockerfile, this will expose the port(s)
  ## just in defined networks
  expose:
    - 5000
  volumes:
    - ./:/usr/src/domain
  restart: always
  command: npm start

networks:
  proxy:
    external:
      name: proxy
```

but after all, i recommend [jwilder/nginx-proxy](https://github.com/nginx-proxy/nginx-proxy)

Comment: I did have a look at `jwilder/nginx-proxy` before, but I don't really get how it should work. Especially, I am confused on this part: `-v /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro`. What are those files and what should they contain? Thank you